# How to check if all elements in an array are equal to a specific number using a for loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix

I made this code to generate a matrix with all elements beeing 1

```
for (fil = 0; fil <= 9; fil++)
    for (col = 0; col <= 9; col++)
        sala[fil][col] = 1;
```

and I was trying to check if all elements are equal to 1 using a for loop and print a message if they were

Comment: Hint: while the `=` operator, which you use correctly in your code snippet, assigns values, `==` tests if two values are equal.

Comment: If there are `10` elements, your loop limits would be `for (fil = 0; fil < 10; fil++)`  Use the same (fixed) loops with `if (sala[fil][col] != 1) { /* handle error */ }`

Comment: Since `sala` is an _array_, code can avoid the explicit `9`.  Inner loop example: `size_t coln = sizeof  sala[fil]/ sizeof sala[fil][0]; for (col = 0; col < coln; col++)
        sala[fil][col] = 1;`.  This insures **all** rather than hopefully _all_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the loop you already have (copied to where you need it to be of course).

Then instead of the assignment, add a check. If `sala[fil][col] != 1` then set a flag (a boolean variable) and break out of the inner loop. In the outer loop check for that flag and if set then break out of the outer loop as well. Both these checks for the flag could be part of the loop condition.

After the outer loop check for the flag. If it is set, then you know that at least one element is not equal to `1`. If the flag is *not* set then you know that *all* elements are equal to `1`.